# SearchView Autocomplete suggestions using Google PLACES Api

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-places-api

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

        this.menu = menu;

        MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        menuItem.setIcon(ColorHelper.tintDrawable(
                ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_search_black_24dp, null),
                ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimary))
        );

        SearchManager searchManager =
                (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);

        final CustomSearchView searchView = (CustomSearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menuItem);
        searchView.setActivity(this);

        CustomSearchView.SearchAutoComplete textArea = searchView.findViewById(R.id.search_src_text);
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(
                searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

        searchView.setSuggestionsAdapter(searchCursorAdapter);

        searchView.setOnSuggestionListener(new CustomSearchView.OnSuggestionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onSuggestionClick(int position) {
                CursorAdapter ca = searchView.getSuggestionsAdapter();
                Cursor cursor = ca.getCursor();
                cursor.moveToPosition(position);

                String placeId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(SearchCursorAdapter.SUGGESTION_ID));
                if (placeId.equals("notPlaceId")) return true;

                loadingDialog.show();
                placesClient.fetchPlace(FetchPlaceRequest.newInstance(placeId,fields))
                        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FetchPlaceResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(FetchPlaceResponse fetchPlaceResponse) {
                        Log.i("PLACE: ",fetchPlaceResponse.getPlace().toString());
                        mapFragment.setFoundPlace(
                                fetchPlaceResponse.getPlace().getLatLng(),
                                fetchPlaceResponse.getPlace().getName(),
                                fetchPlaceResponse.getPlace().getId());
                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

                    }
                });
//                placesClient.getPlaceById(mGoogleApiClient, placeId)
//                        .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<PlaceBuffer>() {
//                            @Override
//                            public void onResult(PlaceBuffer places) {
//                                loadingDialog.dismiss();
//                                if (places.getStatus().isSuccess() && places.getCount() > 0) {
//                                    final Place myPlace = places.get(0);
//                                    Log.i(TAG, "Place found: " + myPlace.getName());
//                                    mapFragment.setFoundPlace(myPlace.getLatLng(), myPlace.getName(), myPlace.getId());
//                                } else {
//                                    Log.e(TAG, "Place not found");
//                                }
//                                places.release();
//                            }
//                        });

                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onSuggestionSelect(int position) {
                return true;
            }
        });
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new CustomSearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
                ViewHelper.hideSoftInput(MapsActivity.this);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(final String suggest) {

                if ((suggest.length() > 1) && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Starting autocomplete query for: " + suggest);

                    Cursor cursor = searchCursorAdapter.getCursor();
                    if ((cursor == null) || (cursor.moveToFirst() && (cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(BaseColumns._ID)) == -1))) {
                        MatrixCursor matrixCursor = new MatrixCursor(new String[]{BaseColumns._ID, SearchCursorAdapter.SUGGESTION_ID});
                        matrixCursor.addRow(new Object[]{-2, getString(R.string.no_place_id)});


                        searchCursorAdapter.changeCursor(matrixCursor);
                        searchCursorAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                    else {

                        AutocompleteSessionToken token = AutocompleteSessionToken.newInstance();
                        RectangularBounds bounds = RectangularBounds.newInstance(WORLD_BOUNDS);

                        final FindAutocompletePredictionsRequest request =
                                FindAutocompletePredictionsRequest
                                        .builder()
                                        .setCountry("KE")
                                        .setLocationBias(bounds)
                                        .setTypeFilter(TypeFilter.ADDRESS)
                                        .setSessionToken(token)
                                        .setQuery(suggest)
                                        .build();

                        Log.i("REQUEST",request.toString());

                        placesClient.findAutocompletePredictions(request)
                                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FindAutocompletePredictionsResponse>() {

                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(FindAutocompletePredictionsResponse findAutocompletePredictionsResponse) {
                                for (AutocompletePrediction prediction : findAutocompletePredictionsResponse.getAutocompletePredictions()) {
                                    Log.i(TAG, prediction.getPlaceId());
                                    Log.i(TAG, prediction.getPrimaryText(null).toString());
                                }

                                List<AutocompletePrediction> predictions = findAutocompletePredictionsResponse.getAutocompletePredictions();
                                MatrixCursor matrixCursor = new MatrixCursor(new String[]{BaseColumns._ID, SearchCursorAdapter.SUGGESTION_ID, SearchCursorAdapter.SUGGESTION_NAME, SearchCursorAdapter.SUGGESTION_EXTRA, SearchCursorAdapter.QUERY});

                                if (predictions.size() > 0) {
                                    for (int i = 0; i < predictions.size(); i++) {
                                        AutocompletePrediction prediction = predictions.get(i);
                                        CharacterStyle style = new StyleSpan(Typeface.NORMAL);
                                        Log.i(TAG, "Suggestion: " + prediction.getFullText(new StyleSpan(Typeface.NORMAL)));
                                        matrixCursor.addRow(new Object[]{i, prediction.getPlaceId(), prediction.getPrimaryText(style), prediction.getSecondaryText(style), suggest});
                                    }
                                }
                                else {
                                    matrixCursor.addRow(new Object[]{-1, getString(R.string.no_place_id),
                                            getString(R.string.primary_location_not_found, suggest),
                                            getString(R.string.secondary_location_not_found), suggest});
                                }

                                searchCursorAdapter.changeCursor(matrixCursor);
                                searchCursorAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }
                        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                if (e instanceof ApiException) {
                                    ApiException apiException = (ApiException) e;
                                    Log.e(TAG, "Place not found: " + apiException.getMessage());
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                } else {
                    searchCursorAdapter.changeCursor(null);
                    searchCursorAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                return true;
            }
        });

        String fontPath = "fonts/" + getString(R.string.font_nunito)
                + "/" + getString(R.string.font_nunito) + "-Regular.ttf";
        textArea.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), fontPath));
        textArea.setHint(R.string.delivery_location);
        textArea.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 15.5f);

        textArea.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(ColorHelper.tintDrawable(
                ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_search_black_24dp, null),
                ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimary)), null, null, null);
        textArea.setCompoundDrawablePadding(ViewHelper.dp2px(this, 10));

        menuItem.expandActionView();

        searchView.setIconified(false);
        searchView.clearFocus();

        return true;
    }
```

I am trying to fetch results of nearby places using Google PLACES API. 
I have embedded the API callback to a searchbar on top of my Maps activity. 
Suggestions should appear as i continue to type on the searchbar.
The suggestions will be displayed as a list from which i can select a place and carry on with my logic using the coordinates of that place
Is there an easier way to implement this functionality?
My query always defaults to an API exception failure.

**This is my logical output**

```
2020-03-26 14:38:42.328 28308-28308/com.mobar.android.mobar I/MapsActivity: Starting autocomplete query for: Ruiru
2020-03-26 14:38:42.330 28308-28308/com.mobar.android.mobar I/REQUEST: FindAutocompletePredictionsRequest{query=Ruiru, locationBias=RectangularBounds{southwest=lat/lng: (-1.430571,36.650945), northeast=lat/lng: (-1.129622,37.120314)}, locationRestriction=null, origin=null, countries=[KE], sessionToken=3173b22c-afc6-4997-9f12-16690a6f7123, typeFilter=ADDRESS, cancellationToken=null}
2020-03-26 14:38:42.343 28308-30243/com.mobar.android.mobar I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
2020-03-26 14:38:42.343 28308-30243/com.mobar.android.mobar I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
2020-03-26 14:38:42.347 7025-7025/? I/SKBD: [ATIM] [updateSelectionForInputModule] oldSelStart : 4, oldSelEnd : 4, newSelStart : 5, newSelEnd : 5, candidatesStart : 0, candidatesEnd : 5, viewClicked : false
2020-03-26 14:38:42.348 7025-7025/? I/SKBD: [ATIM] [updateSelectionForInputModule] isTyping : true, viewClicked : false, isKBDShown : true
2020-03-26 14:38:42.367 28308-28308/com.mobar.android.mobar E/MapsActivity: Place not found: 9011: The provided API key is invalid.
```

The error indicates that the API Key is invalid, this is not true because when i perform a webquery using my API Key, i get results.

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting indicates that the problem is with your API key. First of all, double check that you're [adding your API key](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/start#connect-client) correctly, without any white spaces or extra characters on either end of the key.

Secondly, make sure that it is properly restricted; it needs to be [Android restricted](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/get-api-key#restrict-key) to your app's package name and fingerprint. If you've also added API restrictions, check that Places API is listed. For testing purposes you may also want to temporarily unrestrict it completely and then test if Place Autocomplete works with an unrestricted key.

Hope this helps you!